# How to Store the Output of a for Loop to a Variable

Tags: shell, variable, for

I have the following shell code:

```bash
for value in 10 5 27 33 14  25
do
      echo  $value
done
```

But what if I want to manipulate the output later? I want to store the entire output in one variable. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you wanting to store each of the six numbers in your example to different variables and use them later? Is that what you mean? Or do you really want six lines, each with a number on it, stored in a variable? Or are you really wanting to store the code itself into a variable so you can execute it later?

Comment: I want to store the entire output into one variable, not six lines to different variables or the code itself. Sorry I did not make that clear, I will edit my post.

Comment: The entire output is `10 5 27 33 14  25`. So simply assign it to a variable.

Comment: The example I gave is not what my actual code is. I have something more complicated and I must have it in a for loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's no different with `for` loops than with any other commands, you'd use command substitution:

```
variable=$(
  for value in 10 5 27 33 14  25
  do
    echo "$value"
  done
)
```

Would store the whole output minus the last newline character added by the last `echo` as a string into the scalar `$variable` variable.

You'd then do for instance:

```
printf '%s\n' "$variable" | further-processing
```

Or:

```
futher-processing << EOF
$variable
EOF
```

In the `bash` shell, you can also store each line of the output into an element of an array with:

```
readarray -t array < <(
  for value in 10 5 27 33 14  25
  do
    echo "$value"
  done
)
```

To store each space/tab/newline delimited *word* (assuming the default value of `$IFS`) of the output into an array, you can use the split+glob operator with the glob part disabled

```
set -o noglob # not needed in zsh which does only split upon unquoted
              # command substitution. zsh also splits on NULs by default
              # whilst other shells either removes them or choke on them.
array=(
  $(
    for value in 10 5 27 33 14  25
    do
      echo "$value"
    done
  )
)
```

With `zsh`/`bash`/`ksh93`, you can also do things like:

```
array=()
for value in 10 5 27 33 14 25
do
  array+=( "$(cmd "$value")" )
done
```

To build the array.

Then in all those, you'd do:

```
further-processing "${array[@]}"
```

To pass all the elements of the array as arguments to `futher-processing` or:

```
printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" | further-processing
```

To print each element on one line, piped to `further-processing`

Beware however that if the array is empty, that still prints an empty line. You can avoid that by using `print -rC1 --` instead of `printf '%s\n'` in `zsh` or in any Bourne-like shell, define a function such as:

```
println() {
  [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\n' "$@"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the first solution worked for me!